# Mercurial: How do I find the creator of a file?

Tags: mercurial, posix, file-ownership

ATM I do it this way which is far slow and incorrect:

```
for i in `find -type f`; do
  echo $i`LANG=C hg log -v $i | grep user | tail -1 | awk '{print " "; print $2}'`;
done
```

When someone has moved a file to a new name, yes he is the creator of that new file, but not of the code which he moved. I could extract the revision number out of the first commit and check somehow if this file was renamed.. (sounds very complex)

I just want to know it, for some reason :), since we have no code ownership in our project, it does not matter anyway... :)

Comment: Was the rename/move recorded by Mercurial as a rename/copy/move or as the addition of a new file?

Comment: I cannot assure and hope every developer will make use of "hg mv"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a new-ish version of `hg`, you can use [revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) to make this super-easy:

```
hg log -r 'adds(\"path/to/file\")'
```

(you might have to change the escaping of that, depending on your shell.)

The `adds` function finds the changesets where the given file was added. There are a bunch of other functions; see [revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) or `hg help revsets` for more info.

Comment: Excelent!, I just created a mercurial backport for that :D, great.

Comment: But if I see it correctly, even when hg mv was used, the tracking ends when the file was renamed :(. Unfortunately I found no better function then `adds`, but the command line is much more easier then mine above..

Answer (score 0):

You can make things a little more efficient by changing your `hg log` command to:

```
hg log -r : -l 1 $i --template "{files} {author} {rev}\n"
```

The `-r :` reverses the order of the log output and the `-l 1` shows just the first entry in the log; together, they show the earliest revision of whatever filename is in `$i`.  The `--template` switch customizes the output, in this case, I'm showing the filename, the author and the revision where the file was introduced.  See `hg help templating` for more information.

Another optimization would be to use the output of `hg manifest` piped through `xargs`;  `find -type f` will return all files, so if you've got object files or other untracked files in the working directory, you'll be running `hg log` on them unnecessarily.

Unfortunately, this won't help you find where people have copied files without telling Mercurial about it.

Comment: Adding `-f` will make Mercurial follow the history back across renames.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the author information you can do

```
hg log -r 'first(file("path/to/file"))' --template '{author}\n'
```

as I was suggested by krigstask in #mercurial

9 seconds faster too :)